# mysql 1065 error when trying to add new user for database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, prestashop

im trying to install prestashop on my laptop.
So i've installed xampp as my server + database
Localhost listens to port 8080
And in phpmyadmin i've created a database for prestashop, now i want to set permission for a user.

But i always get a  "#1065 - Query was empty" error upon trying.

This is my query

```
CREATE USER 'prestashop'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '***';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'prestashop'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

I'm pretty lost on where it goes wrong.

Comment: that's two queries... run each one separately and see which fails.